# Is there a way to import external API data into Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, api, rest, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get API data from an external source then input it into Firebase Database, is this possible?

Comment: The question is vague. Are you asking if you can import data into the Real Time Data Base? If not, what are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

To import data from an external source into the Firebase Database, you'll have to write code that gets the data from the external source, and then calls the Firebase API to insert it into the database. There's nothing built into Firebase to do this automatically for you.

One place where you can run such code is in Cloud Functions, for example as a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that periodically updates the data in the database from the external source. Your project will need to be on a paid plan to do so, as the free plan only allows you to access Google's own APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Why do I have to use to paid plan?

Comment: "Your project will need to be on a paid plan to do so, as the free plan only allows you to access Google's own APIs."